# What model year is the Honda Super Cub that Minowa rides in episode 8?

Tags: bakuon

In episode 8 of *Bakuon!!*, when Onsa destroys Hijiri Minowa's license, she rides for her first time a Honda Super Cub that later had outfitted with training wheels and a skull.

I am looking for the year of release for the Minowa's Super Cub bike in order to replicate it.

What model year is the Honda Super Cub that Minowa rides at episode 8?

The one mentioned is:

[image: Hijiri Miniwa Bakuon]

Comment: According to [the official merchandises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwTJz.jpg), she rides **Honda Super Cub 50**. It's also written that the spec listed on that promo image is true, following the real model. However, I still can't pinpoint the model year since it ranges between [1981](http://www.mr-bike.jp/feature/cub/cub_ca-03.html)-now (2018, but the manga was written in 2011)

Comment: Seems an '80s Supercub. I guess in case I find one (eu spec) some mods may needed on read grill and seat except the training wheels and skull.